# Using Swingworker to constantly update a GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, swingworker

In my code, the user presses a button, and then I want this to invoke a SwingWorker background thread, where I basically loop through a list, cross reference it with other data, and then update the GUI with a JLabel for every pass through my loop. The problem is I know I should do this in doInBackground(), but I have nothing to return, and I also want to update the JPanel with a new JLabel every time my loop loops. How do I do this? Thanks!

Comment: You can pass `Void` as a type argument to your `SwingWorker` declaration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a complete example i really like [Swing Worker Example](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/)

You have to use `publish()` and override `process()`

Example:

```
class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground() throws Exception {
       //here you make heavy task this is running in another thread not in EDT
       //process after some time call publish() 


    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        //this is executed in the EDT
        //here you update your label
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Read the Swing tutorial on using a [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) especially the section on `Tasks that Have Interim Results`.

You will want to invoke the `publish()` method as required in your loop.